# Azure CosmosDB SDK ExecuteNextAsync<T> error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

This is in a class library that I'm developing, highly based on the ToDo sample project [Cosmos DB ToDo App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-documentdb-dotnet), to perform the "CRUD" operations on CosmosDB.
However, everytime I call this method, the app will suddenly stop and not give any errors whatsoever.

Here's the code that I'm using to perform reads. Right now, the uncommented code is a synchronous call that provides no issues reading from the database.

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T, E>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : DocDbEntity<E> where E : class
    {
        string documentType = typeof(E).Name;
        IQueryable<T> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId))
            .Where(predicate)
            .Where(x => x.DocumentType == documentType);

        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        foreach (var res in query)
        {
            results.Add(res);
        }

        //IDocumentQuery<T> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
        //    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId))
        //    .Where(predicate)
        //    .Where(x => x.DocumentType == documentType)
        //    .AsDocumentQuery();

        //while (query.HasMoreResults)
        //{
        //    results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
        //}

        return results;
    }
```

Whenever I try to use `query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>()` my application will immediately terminate without giving any errors or pointing to what might be causing the issue nor will it "reply" to the request with the retrieved data.
This seems to be working without any issues on the sample app.

I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB package from NuGet @ version 1.19.1

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is not related in any way to ExecuteNextAsync but it was rather than the function that was calling this method returned `void`, thus preventing the parent caller from waiting for a reply. Once I started returning a Task everything started to work as expected.

Comment: The reason this happens is because `async void` functions, while allowing you to use `await` within them, run synchronously until the first `await` it then returns immediately (along with its delegate handler). This means that even if you have `await`s in it, your delegate  handler is gone and so is the ability to return to that method after the first `await`.